# Why does my motion is not working properly? fadeIn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

So I'm still learning Framer-Motion and I want to move my div when I scroll down but its not working properly, so this is my event component

Events.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
import { fadeIn, slideIn } from '../motion'
const Events = () => {
  return (
    <div className='px-4 py-10 h-full'>
        <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full gap-10'>
            <p className='text-lg text-slate-800 font-semibold'>Events</p>

            <div className='flex items-center justify-center'>
                <motion.div
                  variants={fadeIn('left','tween', 0.3, 1)}
                  className='flex flex-col  justify-center gap-10'
                >
                    <h2 className='text-3xl'>Platinum Award</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sed ad libero eius totam omnis obcaecati amet dolores quod cumque eveniet recusandae, eos dolore nostrum corrupti.</p>
                </motion.div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Events
```

And I'm importing the motion |

```
  export const fadeIn = (direction, type, delay, duration) => ({
    hidden: {
      x: direction === 'left' ? 100 : direction === 'right' ? -100 : 0,
      y: direction === 'up' ? 100 : direction === 'down' ? -100 : 0,
      opacity: 0,
    },
    show: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        type,
        delay,
        duration,
        ease: 'easeOut',
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: no animation happens